# how to backup CnosDB meta cluster data

Tags: database, rust, cluster-computing, cnosdb

Can cnosdb implement backup meta cluster data? I would like to know some plans of cnosdb in this regard.

CnosDB should implement this feature

Comment: why do you need to back up meta data? or you mean, back up meta data only?

Answer (score 0):

To back up metadata, you can use the following method:(8901 is the configured meta listening port)

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8901/dump
```

Hope this helps you